# How to search column for string in list and make new column containing all instances

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to scan a certain column `df['description']` for keywords listed in `keyword = ['x', 'y', 'z']`. I would like python to load all keywords found, so if description contains `x` and `y`, it would show both.

Currently the code I have is as such, but it only returns 1 keyword as opposed to all instances:

````
keyword = ['x','y','z']
pattern = '|'.join(keyword)
def pattern_searcher(search_str: str, search_list: str):
    found_objects = re.findall(search_list, search_str)
    return found_objects if found_objects else ""
df['keyword'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: pattern_searcher(search_str=x, search_list=pattern))```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. expand and explode
2. test
3. combine matched items

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"description":["hello world is here","foo is always a name"]})
keyword = ["is", "here", "name"]
df = df.assign(words=df["description"].str.split(" ")).explode("words")
df = df.assign(test=df["words"].isin(keyword))
df = df.loc[df["test"]].groupby("description").agg({"words":lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
df
```

**output**

```
    description words
0   foo is always a name    [is, name]
1   hello world is here [is, here]
```